# What exception to throw when you get 500 response code

Tags: c#, exception

I want to know what type of exception to throw when I get 500 response code.
I have my code something like

```
_logger is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

HttpResponseMessage response = await Something.configureAwait(false);

if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  //do something as it is 200 response
}
else if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeOut)
{
   _logger.LogError(response.StatusCode + "some Message");
  throw new HttpResponseException //error : type or namespace could not be found
} 
else
{
   _logger.LogError(response.StatusCode + "some Message");
  //Any other error code it means, there is something wrong in my code like 400, 404 (I passed incorrect url), 203 (again my issue).
}
```

I just want the user to retry if it is 500 and for the other cases, I would take care with unit test.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: "I want the user to retry if it is 500." Users do not catch exceptions. Some part of your system (which you haven't told us about) catches that exception and displays something to the end user. The answer to your question depends on whatever that is. In some cases, you wouldn't throw an exception at all.

Comment: @JohnWu User writes cmd from cmdLine and we use Microsoft Logger. `_logger is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. Updated the code.